# google-api-nodejs-client get google contacts

Tags: node.js, google-api

I'm trying to get my google contacts list with nodejs.

I'm just following what is said on the "https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/" page but I received an error when calling "new OAuth2".

Below the simple code

```
var googleapis = require('googleapis');

var OAuth2 = googleapis.auth.OAuth2,
    client_id = '21486685252.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    client_secret = '*********',
    redirect_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/google/return',
    oauth2Client = new OAuth2(client_id, client_secret, redirect_url);
```

Below the error received :

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\passport\google\passport-google-login.js:15:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Did you use `passport-js` for importing contacts?